# What's a good home-based learning curriculum for a 2-year-old?

Tags: toddler, education, homeschooling, stay-at-home

I have a 2-year-old son who is a fast developer.

He has been attending play school some mornings and will only join a school towards the end of the year.

I am looking for a home-based learning curriculum / set of exercises / home school program for his age that his nanny can take him through for an hour or two every day. I'm covering things like colours, shapes, words etc. to keep him stimulated and learning.

What would be a good home-based learning curriculum for my toddler?

Answer (score 3):

The best schooling for a two year old consists of reading to him and playing with him, and taking him frequently outside to parks and play groups where he can socialize with other kids his age.

At two, some of the books he might be interested in that would also be very intellectually stimulating include photo books which consist of nothing but photos of real objects (and the word for them to help Daddy!).   Priddy Books for example has some great ones, as does DK and several other publishers.

For example, a book with all of the different kinds of construction vehicle, or trains, or trucks, or animals.  Many of these include color pages (so, a page of only orange trucks, a page of only blue trains, or a page with one of each major color), number pages (one truck, two train cars, three dogs, four sheep), shapes pages (a rectangle freight truck, a triangle digger shovel, an oval concrete mixer) and even sometimes alphabet pages (A is for anteater, B is for bear, etc.)

These realistic photo books are very good for teaching, because at that age they're very interested in their environment and they are able to recognize the photos as more "real" than the fluffy hand drawn stuff of one-year-old books.  We have gone through at least a dozen of these kinds of books with our two boys (now 2 and almost 4) and they're wonderful for learning and keeping their interest, far better than books with any sort of 'plot' at that age.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more structured learning curriculum, ABC Jesus Loves Me has a lot of awesome materials and free resources. The only warning I would give is it is a LOT to expect of a 2 year old to be able to do 3 days a week if you try to do it exactly as they have it laid out. My suggestion would be to pick and choose things based on your child’s interests and have fun! That tends to be my approach with my 2 year old, see what excites him and find ways to integrate material you want to teach him through those avenues. For example, my son LOVES to push the buttons on the microwave, so we use that as an opportunity for number recognition when he helps warm up food.